# jQuery UI datepicker - TypeError: O is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, datepicker

I am making CakePHP app, and currently I am writing script to issue ajax request to highlight reserved days for jQuery datePicker, and onSelect make another Ajax request to show information about reservations on specific day, using jQuery Accordion.

However, my calendar doesn't show, and I get error in Firebug Console - "Type Error: O is undefined. function i(t, i){ in jquery-ui.custom.min.js file". Script was working perfectly before implementing highlight of some days.

View (calendar.ctp):

```
<?php 
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Calendar'));
    $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.custom', null, array('inline' => false));
    $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.custom.min', array('inline' => false));  
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3" id="datepicker"></div>
    <div class="span7" id="hours"></div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'streservations', 'action' => 'highlight'), true);?>',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,           
        data: {
            action : 'showdates'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(reservations){   
            //alert(reservations[0][0]);
            console.log(reservations);
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ //initialize datepicker
                defaultDate: '<?php echo $this->Time->format('Y-m-d', time()) ?>',
                maxDate: '<?php echo $this->Time->format('Y-m-d', '+1 month') ?>',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){                        
                    var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
                    var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                    var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
                    if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                    if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit                        
                    var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
                    console.log(currDate);
                    /*
                    $.each(reservations, function(k, v){
                        //alert(v.date + ' ' + v.count);
                        if(v.date == currDate && v.count > 3){
                            return [true, "ui-highlight"];
                        }
                        else{
                            return [true];
                        }
                    });
                    /*for(var i = 0; i < reservations.lenght; i++){
                        alert(reservations[i][1]);
                        if(*reservations[i][1] == currDate*reservations.indexOf(currDate) >= 0){
                            return [true, "ui-highlight"];  
                        }else{
                            return [true];
                        }
                    }*/                     
                },
                onSelect : function(dateText,inst) //when selecting date, make AJAX call to show accordion
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'streservations', 'action' => 'hours'), true);?>',
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            action: 'accord',
                            date: dateText
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#hours").accordion({collapsible: true, clearStyle: true, heightStyle: "content"});
                            $('#hours').empty();
                            $.each(data, function(k, v){
                                $('#hours').append('<li><h3><div>' + v.title + ' ' + v.start + '</div></h3><div>' + 'Operation: ' + v.name + '</br>' + 'Name: ' + v.title + '</br>'+ 'Time: ' + v.start + '</br>'+'</div></li>');
                            });
                            $("#hours").accordion( "refresh" );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

Update: 
So, I changed script version to development one(jquery-ui.custom) and now I get this error:

TypeError: daySettings is undefined

```
unselectable = (otherMonth && !selectOtherMonths) || !daySettings[0] ||
```

Comment: Minified versions of scripts are for production, not development. Use the full script to get better error information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: I needed to return array in beforeShowDay function:

```
               beforeShowDay: function(date){                        
                    var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
                    var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                    var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
                    if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                    if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit                        
                    var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
                    console.log(currDate);                        
                    //return [true, "ui-highlight", ''];                         

                    for(var i = 1; i < reservations.lenght; i++){
                        console.log(reservations[i].date);
                        if(reservations[i].date == currDate){
                            return [true, 'ui-highlight', ''];  
                        }/*else{
                            return [true];
                        }*/

                    }
                    return [true, '', ''];
                },
```

But None of my Days get highlighted, this code somehow doesnt get executed:

```
if(reservations[i].date == currDate){
                            return [true, 'ui-highlight', ''];  
                        }
```

My reservations JSON array is: `[Object { date="2014-07-18", count="3"}, Object { date="2014-08-05", count="1"}, Object { date="2014-08-06", count="2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you spelt "length" wrong:

```
 for(var i = 1; i < reservations.lenght; i++){
```